# How to prove that the intersection of a continuous and continuously differentiable function and a plane has a finite domain

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry

I have a function $y = f(x): \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a plane $y = k$ such that $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^N} f(x) \leq k \leq \max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^N} f(x)$.

If my function $f(x)$ is continuous and continuously differentiable everywhere, and tends asymptotically to some value $u$ such that $\lim_{|x| \to \infty}f(x) = u$, how can I prove that the intersection of $f(x) = k$ such that $k \neq u$ is a finite region and/or has a finite domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand your limit to $\infty$ definition. But if you assume that there exists an $\epsilon>0$, and an $R$ such that $f(B_R(0)^c) \cap (k-\epsilon,k+\epsilon) = \emptyset$, then what u want is immediate. Let $U = f^{-1}(k-\epsilon,k+\epsilon)$. If $U$ is unbounded then for every $R$, there is an $m \in U \cap B_{R}(0)^c$. But then $|f(m)-k|>\epsilon$ by the fact that $f(B_R(0)^c) \cap (k-\epsilon,k+\epsilon) = \emptyset$ and $|f(m)-k| < \epsilon$ by the definition of $U$. This is a contradiction. Hence $U$ is bounded.

The assumption that: $f(B_R(0)^c) \cap (k-\epsilon,k+\epsilon) = \emptyset$ is similar to the assumption that for every unbounded sequence $x_n$, $\{f(x_n)\}$ either converges to a limit other than $k$ or bounded away from $k$ for all $n \geq N$ for some $N$.

Limit at infinity sense 1:
Assuming there exists $R$ such that :
$\sup_{x \in B_R(0)^c} |f(x)-u| < \epsilon$ so that we have $f(B_R(0)^c) \cap (k-\epsilon,k+\epsilon) = \emptyset$ where $\epsilon =(|u-k|/4)$. $B_R(0) = \{x: ||x|| \leq R\}$.

Limit at infinity sense 2:
Assuming for every unbounded $\{y_i\}$, $f(y_i) \rightarrow u$:
Suppose for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $x_N \in B_N(0)^c \cap f^{-1}((k-\epsilon,k+\epsilon))$, then the sequence $\{f(x_N)\} \subseteq (k-\epsilon,k+\epsilon)$, but since the sequence $\{x_N\}$ is unbounded there exists an $M$ such that $|f(x_i)-u|< \epsilon$, $\forall i \geq M$. This is a contradiction by choosing $\epsilon =(|u-k|/4)$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I mean by the limit is that as the point $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ gets far from the origin, then the function will tend asymptotically towards the value $u$. In your response, what are $R$ and $B$?

Comment: $R$ is some number such that $\sup_{x \in B_R(0)^c} |f(x)-u| < \epsilon$ so that we have $f(B_R(0)^c) \cap (k-\epsilon,k+\epsilon) = \emptyset$. $B_R(0) = \{x: ||x|| \leq R\}$.

Comment: @Philliams have edited my answer. Pls take a look.